# How to convert XML bean from org.springframework into annotation

Tags: java, xml, spring

I'd like to convert xml bean creating into annotations. I've converted few already, but I have problem with this one:

```
<bean id="anyClass" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="target">
        <bean class="pl.spring.demo.class.impl.AnyClassImpl">
            <property name="anyName" ref="anyName" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>anyValue</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Could you add more details to the question, why your previous approach is not working here, what problem are you facing, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to try with Spring Java Beans, you can try out like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ProxyFactoryBeanConfiguration{

    @Autowired
    private pl.spring.demo.class.impl.AnyClassImpl anyClassImpl;

    @Autowired
    private List<String> interceptorNames;

    @Bean
    public org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean anyClass(){
        ProxyFactoryBean proxyFactoryBean = new ProxyFactoryBean();
        proxyFactoryBean.setTarget(anyClassImpl);
        proxyFactoryBean.setInterceptorNames(interceptorNames);
        return proxyFactoryBean;
    }

}
```

Make sure that you are injecting anyClassImpl with the required dependencies.